# Python - TypeError

Tags: python

```
abir=float(15.67)
aiki=float(17.23) 
auc=float(0.75)
adort=float(93.2)
abes=float
be=float
an=float
kn=float
kontrol=1
x=float
def giris():
        print("Yari-Deneysel Kutle Formulunden Yararlanarak Baglanma Enerjisini Bulmak Icin :")       
        an=input("Atom Numarasini Giriniz  : ")
        global kn
        global x
        kn=an
        x=an*3
        print(an,kn,x)
        a=float(abir*kn)
        b=float(aiki*(kn**(2.0/3.0)))
        c=float(auc*(an**2)/(kn**(1.0/3.0)))
        d=float(adort*((kn-(2*an))**2)/kn)
        e=float(abes/(kn**(0.5)))
        be=a-b-c-d+e
        nb=float(be/kn)
        print("Atom Numarasi :",kn)
        print("Kutle Numarasi :",an)
        print("Toplam Baglanma Enerjisi : ",be," MeV'dir.")
        print("Nukleon Basi Baglanma Enerjisi : ",nb," MeV'dir.")
        print(kn)
        kn+=1
def nokontrol():
        if kn>0:
                if an>0:
                        if kn%2==0:
                                if an%2==0:
                                        abes=12
                                        formul()
                                        kontrol=0
                                else:
                                        abes=0
                                        formul()
                                        kontrol=0
                        else:
                                if an%2==0:
                                        abes=0
                                        formul()
                                        kontrol=0
                                else:
                                        abes=-12
                                        formul()
                                        kontrol=0
                elif an<0:
                        print("Atom Numarasi Sifirdan Kucuk Olamaz.")
                else:
                        print("Atom Numarasi Sifir Olamaz.")
        elif kn<0:
                print("Kutle Numarasi Sifirdan Kucuk Olamaz.")
        elif kn==0 and an==0:
                print("Kutle Numarasi ve Atom Numarasi Sifir Olamaz.")
while kontrol==1:        
        giris()
        while an==x:
                nokontrol()
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    a=float(abir*kn)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Result:
Yari-Deneysel Kutle Formulunden Yararlanarak Baglanma Enerjisini Bulmak Icin ;
Atom Numarasini Giriniz  : 28
28 28 282828

```
28 * 3 = 282828 ??? correct : 28 * 3 = 84?
```

Help Me Please, I just started in Python, for physics learning. If you correct my mistake I'd appreciate it. The code is in python 3.3. The parameters are Atomic number `an`, mass number `kn`. `"an==3*kn"` will continue to increase until is 1 kn. It extended to all "formul()" implements the printing of the result. Float type is wrong. d of lonely.I could not fix this error is a kinWhat can i do? My English not good, sorry

Comment: above, `kn` does not have a valid value, you just say `kn=float`. Assign something to that parameter

Answer (score 3):

At the fifth line of `giris`

```
kn=an
```

you set `kn` to string which is the sequence, python complains about.

Comment: Ahh, this solves the mystery.  `an` is a string because it is the return value of `input` (remember py3k).  +1 for tracking this down.

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning several of your variables (`abes`, `be`, `an`, `kn`, and `x`) to the function `float`, rather than to an actual floating-point value. Then when you try to multiply this times anything else, you get a `TypeError` because you can't multiply `type` objects. If you want to initialize these values outside the function, just set them to `0` or `None`.

Of course, your *specific* problem is that you then reassign `kn=an` after you've assigned `an` to a string from your `input` call. That's why Python complains about a "sequence". But like I said, you've got bigger problems than just that.

Answer (score 1):

The following doesn't do what you might be expecting:

```
abes=float
be=float
an=float
kn=float
```

If you simply want to initialize them to zero, write

```
abes=0.0
```

etc

Also, the

```
abir=float(15.67)
```

can be written as

```
abir=15.67
```

etc. The `float()` call is redundant.

The same goes for

```
a=float(abir*kn)
```

etc.

Finally, somewhere in the code you don't show you are turning `abir` into a sequence (e.g. a list or a tuple).

Comment: This is true, but I'm really struggling to find a sequence in there ... so I still can't explain the traceback from this.

Comment: Actually I think every single one of his `float()` calls is unnecessary?

Comment: @FrancisAvila: Pretty much.

Comment: As it stands, this would give an error like:  `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'type' and 'float'` I think ...

Comment: @mgilson: Sure. I've just been adding some wording about `abir` becoming a sequence somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I got no idea what you're trying to do there...

step one: on the way to fix it (and your Python-experience): remove all those 'floats', there... Python is dynamically typed, no need to declare a type.

If you write something like 'i=float' you don't declare i of the type float, but you assign the value 'float' (which is a type) to the name 'i'.
If you follow up with 5*i, your program essentially means '5 times type float', which doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting 28*3 = 282828, what's actually going on is that 28 is a string. '28'*3 is '282828'. You can change the string into an int with `int('28')` or a float with `float('28')`

From looking at your code, I think this is happening at the line

```
an=input("Atom Numarasini Giriniz  : ")
```

Try changing it to

```
an=int(input("Atom Numarasini Giriniz  : "))
```